# Zooming or scrolling wont work in phonegap with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I'm making a phonegap app, and i'm having trouble with zooming and scrolling, I have a page and all it has on it is an image, i dont have the width or anything set, so its zoomed in (which is fine) but then I cant zoom out using pinch to zoom, or even scroll around the image, does anyone know what my problem is? Thanks :)

Comment: did u set some meta viewport settings on the html header? (not sure if phonegap did it for u), something like this: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=160dpi, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">

Comment: @Yman <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3, user-scalable=yes">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JQtouch Photo gallery plugin-

http://code.google.com/p/jqextensions/wiki/JQTouchPhotoGallery

Demo - [here](http://samshull.com/jqtouch-r148/demos/main/#home).

If you don't like JQtouch you can used-

PhotoSwipe lib - http://www.photoswipe.com/

I have tested both the example in Phonegap app for iOS and its work like charm.